# What should I do about people who make an answer that didn't seem to read the question?

Tags: discussion

I have had it happen multiple times where a person answers my question in a way that seems to imply they didn't read the whole question. The most recent example of this was https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/90665/78566

What should I do here? Is my question not clear enough? Should I flag and/or downvote the answer? Comment on the question?

Comment: I am sure you meant flag and/or downvote the answer and not the question :D In any case, don't flag the answer unless it is of terribly low quality (or) makes absolutely no attempt to answer the question. Flags shouldn't be used for wrong answers. You can use your votes as you wish.

Comment: @Harry indeed, thank you. Question and answer were going through my brain so much that I think they crashed and got jumbled.

Comment: You've gotten good generic advice here, but if you want to discuss that specific question in particular, you should ask on [Meta Web Apps](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @AlE. I've had this happen multiple times, so generic advice is exactly what I wanted. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 7):

First, check if you have done enough. Check if your question is clear and answerable. Did you left out some important details? If so, add them.

Second, comment on the answer. Explain why it doesn't answer your question. See if the author has misunderstood the question or is missing some details you left out.

Ultimately you can downvote the answer. It is best to comment to since the author and other viewers might think the answer is okay and worth an upvote.

Flagging is not really an option if the answer actually attempting to answer the question.